# Magento Order Comments from Admin Panel are auto sent to customers

Tags: magento, comments, orders

I have a problem in `Magento 1.8`

From Admin Panel, when I open an Order (whose invoice is generated), then I go to `Comment History` section, add new status (like, `Processing` : `Making` ) to that order, then I put some comments in the given TextArea.

Now, as I don't want the end customer to know about this comment of mine, the `Notify Customer by Email` checkbox is left unchecked. And then I submit the comment.

The customer gets a notification mail regarding this comment update.

Is this Magento Default behaviour or I am missing something. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you working on some existing project, if yes there may be customization for this functionality. Check local modules.

Comment: No, it is not an existing project, but I don't know if any installed module is doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem ::

If I disable **Order Comments** from **System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email**, the customer is not notified any more.

Comment: But admin is also not getting email if we disable this

Answer (score 1):

for anyone running into this problem in future. We run into this "problem" as well and found out the following:

In the sendOrderUpdateEmail (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) I found this :

```
// Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is
// 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
   foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
      $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
      $emailInfo->addTo($email);
      $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
   }
}
```

This set me thinking: We had System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > Order Comments enabled.
And we had a BCC send to us of every comment.

So we tested this: made a comment without customer notification and a BCC was send to us but no mail was send to the customer.
Made a second comment with customer notification and both the customer and we got a mail.

So this may seem a bug or a problem but it just the strange way it is coded in Magento:
If the customer is NOT notified but you have a BCC or Copy of notification emails YOU will get an email. This can be very confusing: it looks like the client gets the notification but that is not the case, only the copy or bcc is send...